# How to use eleonora in xenoblade chronicles x?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

Is there something I need to do first to be able to use eleornora to level my field skills? I am currently on chapter 3 and my blade level is 3 but when I talk to her all I can do is inquire about missions which all she talks about is the mission I'm on. And discuss if anything is bothering her which she says she is OK and that I could ask others if they are alright. I dont get an option to upgrade my skills

Answer (score 2):

After you beat chapter 3 you can talk to her about leveling up your field skills as that's after you complete your blade training.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you that was a big help I was getting confused